# How to get the id of highest total from all groups? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have following table

```
id   Salary 
1     5
2     3
1     3
1     6
2     5
3     5
3     2
4     1
4     3
2     9
```

I want to get the id of highest total(sum) salary from all groups. In this case the result should be id=2 sum=17( i.e. 3+5+9 = 17)

Comment: What is your primary key

Comment: Primary key is a long auto incremented value .

Answer (score 4):

If you really only expect/need a single `id` group, then using `LIMIT` is probably the most straightforward approach here:

```
SELECT id, SUM(Salary) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY SUM(Salary) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If there could be ties for the highest salary, then we would need to do more work.  Before MySQL 8+, the query given by @MKhalid is what we would need to do.  Starting with MySQL 8+, we can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```
SELECT id, total
FROM
(
    SELECT id, SUM(Salary) AS total,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC) rank
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Is there any way of getting the same result with out "ORDER BY" ?

Comment: No...ordering descending by the sum of salary is the crux of the logic of this query.

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTEName AS
(SELECT id, SUM(salary) as total_salary from testTable 
GROUP BY id ) 
select top 1 id from CTEName ORDER BY total_salary desc

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax, and while MySQL 8 might support CTE, it still uses `LIMIT`.

Comment: this is not MySQL